How to limit search directories when searching references or when refactoring?
I noticed that VSC searches in all directories when I click on "Find all references" or "Rename symbols"/"Change all occurrences".
Usually, I want to do this only in my source files, the files I wrote. Not the files in  the sub-folders where the internal or third-party libraries live.
I'm aware, usually it exclude automatically those file in the refactoring preview, but including it in the search phase leads to long time to present the result.
Is there a way to exclude the directories I don't want to search in?

You have the 3 dots under the replace all fields. There you can specify a regex to exclude files/folders you do not want


Thanks, but I'm not talking about the "Search" feature. In my question I said: "Find all references" or "Rename symbols"/"Change all occurrences"

The Find all references does not support filtering. You can achieve same results in Search bar where you can filter them based on locations
